# How do I convert a razor page with an injection to a code-behind?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, dependency-injection, code-behind, blazor

I'm modifying a blazor example from [Blazor Tips and Tricks][1]

[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3duXMxwnkXI starting at the 17 minute mark.

If you create a new ***Blazor App*** named BlazorCounter in Visual Studio, and modify the generated Counter.razor to look like this:

```html
@page "/counter"
@inject Data.CounterState State

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @State.CurrentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        State.CurrentCount++;
    }
}
```

Then add the following c# class to the Data folder 

`namespace BlazorCounter.Data
{
    public class CounterState
    {
        public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
    }
}`

Finally add this line at the end of the ConfigureServices method of Startup class:

```
            services.AddScoped<CounterState>();
```

Then you have a counter which preserves its state and doesn't start at zero every time you navigate to the Counter page.

My question is: How do I convert this to 'code-behind' and separate the C# code?
I've converted other razor pages to 'code-behind', but don't see how to handle the @inject line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Base class and inject the service with an **`[InjectAttribute]`**:

```cs
public class MyCounterComponent : ComponentBase
{

    [Inject]
    public virtual CounterState State { get; set; }

    protected void IncrementCount()
    {
        State.CurrentCount++;
    }
}
```

I also move your `IncrementCount()` method from the view file to this class file.

And now you can use it with a `@inherits` directive:

```
@page "/counter"
@inherits BlazorApp1.Pages.MyCounterComponent

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @State.CurrentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

For more details, see [Request a service in a component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#request-a-service-in-a-component) and [Use DI in services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#use-di-in-services)

Comment: Your answer works great! This Blazor component preserves the counter state across all the web pages. How do I create a component that preserves the count on a per-page basis?

Comment: @HalHeinrich Seems that there's no built-in Component scoped service available. But as a walkaround, we can inject a `IServiceProvider` and create a new scope by `sp.CreateScope()` .